Identify a short psychological thriller film for me
Saw a psychological short film recommended by Film Riot(Youtube Channel) some 5-6 months ago, but I cant remember the title.
The Film starts off with a scene of a man being taken out of his room in an mental asylum to your typical interrogation room. 
Inside the room there is around 10-15 other men and women with different ages and personalities, all huddled up into one side of the table while a doctor sits calmly on the other side. It can be inferred that these men and women are also mentally ill. They argue and argue (not sure about what), and the doctor keeps on acting as a figure of authority and reason. The Man we were introduced with earlier stays silent.
The Doctor is finally able to get everyone to calm down, stands up and places her hand on the man's shoulder. Everyone else in the room suddenly disappears, and it is revealed that all of them, including the Doctor, represent the multiple personalities the man has, with the Doctor acting as the only 'sane' personality. 
Another Doctor then enters the room (not a personality) and begins asking questions to the man. 

What do you mean by 'short film'? As in, under an hour or something like that? Were there any big names in  the film? What was the production like? Was it an American movie?
My first thought was Identity - it kinda fits but it also kind of doesn't.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(film)

where/how did you watch it?  was it American, in English?  color, live action?  do you know how old the film was?

I think maybe I have found it.
This short film is titled, Inside.
It's from 2002, directed by Trevor Sands, and stars Jeremy Sisto.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298934/



